# when the gcm message received, wake lock screen does not work in android 4.1.3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, wakelock

We are developing an Android app. 
We are going to wake up Lock-mode, when our App receives a GCM message in Sleep mode.

program works well in Android 4.1 (Jelly-Bean, API 16).
but it does not work in Android 4.3 (Jelly-Bean, API 19). 
What is the problem? Please let us know!!!

**We programmed as follows:**

**follow is class files :**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //...some code omitted...

    Intent newIntent;
    newIntent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
    newIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
}
}


public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...some code omitted...
    WakeLockManager.setWakeUp(this);
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onStart();
}   
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onStart();    
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onStop() {
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onStop();
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //...some code omitted...
    super.onDestroy();
}   
}


public class WakeLockManager {
public static void setWakeUp(Context context) {
    Window wnd = ((Activity)context).getWindow();
    wnd.addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        );
}
}
```

**follow is manifest file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>       
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>    

<application
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.mycompany.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.GCMIntentService" /> 

    <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.activities.SomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appkorea.newdriver.activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AuthTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>                
    </activity>     

    <!-- ...some code omitted... -->          

</application>

</manifest>
```

**in case of API 19, when staring SomeActivity, the onCreate() call-back function is called over 1 times.
I guess several reason as follow.**

```
1. SomeActivity's screenOrientation value is landscape. 
   So for rotating activity, the onCreate() call-back function is called once.
2. To unlock the lockScreen, the android system show the lock screen, 
   and rotate the screen into portrait. 
   because current lock-screen's screenOrientation value is portrait. 
   At this time, SomeActivity is already created. 
   so the onCreate call-back function is called once.
3. After unlocking, To show the SomeActivity, the onCreate() is called once. 
   but now device screenOrientation is portrait, 
   and SomeActivity's screenOrientation is landscape. 
   so the onCreate() is called again.
```

As above that is written, onCreate() is called over 1 times. Unfortunately I don't have a android phone 4.3 now. So I can not show the logcat. Later soon, I will upload the logcat screen capture. Really Thanks to read.